# npm test fails on the query function (Hyperledger Composer)

Tags: eslint, hyperledger-composer

I'm successfully calling named queries on my transaction functions code on Hyperledger Composer. The problem is that when I try to run the set of tests with `npm test`, I get the following error:

```
error  'query' is not defined  no-undef
```

For demonstrating purposes, I have generated a new business network skeleton with `yo hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork` to which I added a queries.qry file with the folllowing query:

```
query getParticipant{
  description: "Get participants with given first name"
  statement:
    SELECT org.acme.mynetwork.SampleParticipant WHERE (firstName == _$firstName)
}
```

I have also modified the lib/logic.js file to have a transaction that will call the previous query, with the following code:

```
async function sampleTransaction(tx) {

    let participant = await query('getParticipant', { firstName: 'Alice' });
    console.log(participant);
}
```

This code works as expected on the deployed network. When submitting a dummy sampleTransaction, I can then see the participant Alice printed on the docker log. However, the `npm test` fails with the error before mentioned.

Maybe there is something missing on the .eslintrc.yml file, automatically generated by yeoman... I really don't know...

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? It would really ease the development process to be able to correctly run all the tests before deploying new code to the business network.

For reference, the only thing I found on the Internet about the problem was this open issue with no comments on the Hyperledger Composer github:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3775

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is eslint complaining about your TP function. You need to tell eslint about global functions it doesn't know about. If you look in the Trade network as an example here
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js#L15
you will see how you can inform eslint of a global function declaration.
I've included the line here as it is a single one line comment

`/* global getAssetRegistry getFactory emit query */`

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! I'm not very familiar with eslint and would have never guessed that this one line comment was how I could inform it about unknown global functions.

Answer (score 0):

there are queries defined in tests in the composer-sample-networks repo -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks

Examples:

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/test/trading.js#L153

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/pii-network/test/pii.js#L161

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply. 

I'm aware of this kind of usage of queries, recurring to the businessNetworkConnection and I have already written some programs that use them. 

But the issue here is on the transaction code itself, that will be deployed to the network and executed every time I submit a new transaction. Here I don't think it would make sense or even work to instantiate a businessNetworkConnection and I don't need to because the code works fine. The problem only arises when I run `npm test` and it checks the syntax of the transaction code, the query call is not recognized.